# Can I tell Biblatex to put contributor type in parentheses after the contributor names instead of in a phrase before them with style authoryear?

Tags: biblatex, styles

I am working on a project and need a specific style of Heimildir (i.e. References). I've got everything almost like I want:

[image: references]

Except that I need the phrase "Gefið út af" (equivalent to "Edited by" in English) to appear after the editor name/s as "(ritstj.)" (equivalent to "(ed./eds.)" in English). I know I can do this with Bibtex and APA style, but the APA style only puts initials and not full names which is what I need. I am using a babel package which substitutes common phrases (e.g. "bls." for "pp.") so I think all I really need is a way to move that "contributor type" field.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}{citelist.bib}
@book{enisskola,
    langid = {icelandic},
    options = {useeditor=false},
    year={1986},
    title = {Ensk-íslensk skólaorðabók},
    editor = {{Jón Skaptason}},
    publisher = {Örn og Örlygur},
    location = {Reykjavík}
    }  

@incollection{lucy1997,
    langid = {british},
    address = {Cambridge},
    year = {1997},
    title = {The linguistics of \lq color\rq},
    booktitle = {Color Categories in Thought and Language},
    author = {John A. Lucy},
    editor = {Clyde L. Hardin and Luisa Maffi},
    publisher = {Cambridge University Press},
    location = {Cambridge},
    pages = {320--346}
    }
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[LY1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[icelandic]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage[sortlocale=auto,backend=biber,style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{citelist.bib}

\begin{document}


citations:  \\
I cited \cite{enisskola}    \\
I cited \cite{lucy1997} \\

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Just to clarify: Do you still want the name of the editor after the `booktitle` (i.e. 'in *Booktitle*. Edith Ditor (ed.)') or do you want the name moved in front of the `booktitle` (as in APA style, i.e. 'in Edith Ditor (ed.): *Booktitle*'.)

Comment: @moewe, I want the editor to stay after the book title, like in the first example (and I have an option set in the .bib file to suppress the APA way). I'll drop in the MWF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get what you want by copying the code from the `editor...` macros to the `byeditor...` macros.

The following should be a start.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[icelandic]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\DeclareDelimFormat{editortypedelim}{\addspace}

\DeclareFieldAlias{translatortype}{editortype}
\DeclareDelimAlias{translatortypedelim}{editortypedelim}

\renewbibmacro*{byeditor}{%
  \ifnameundef{editor}
    {}
    {\printnames{editor}%
     \setunit{\printdelim{editortypedelim}}%
     \usebibmacro{editorstrg}%
     \clearname{editor}}%
  \usebibmacro{byeditorx}}

\newbibmacro*{editorstrg:x}[1]{%
  \printtext[editortype]{%
    \iffieldundef{#1type}
      {\ifboolexpr{
         test {\ifnumgreater{\value{#1}}{1}}
         or
         test {\ifandothers{#1}}
       }
         {\bibstring{editors}}
         {\bibstring{editor}}}
      {\ifbibxstring{\thefield{#1type}}
         {\ifboolexpr{
            test {\ifnumgreater{\value{#1}}{1}}
            or
            test {\ifandothers{#1}}
          }
            {\bibstring{\thefield{#1type}s}}
            {\bibstring{\thefield{#1type}}}}
         {\thefield{#1type}}}}}

\renewbibmacro*{byeditorx}{%
  \ifnameundef{editora}
    {}
    {\printnames{editora}%
     \setunit{\printdelim{editortypedelim}}%
     \usebibmacro{editorstrg:x}{editora}}%
  \ifnameundef{editorb}
    {}
    {\printnames{editorb}%
     \setunit{\printdelim{editortypedelim}}%
     \usebibmacro{editorstrg:x}{editorb}}%
  \ifnameundef{editorc}
    {}
    {\printnames{editorc}%
     \setunit{\printdelim{editortypedelim}}%
     \usebibmacro{editorstrg:x}{editorc}}}

\renewbibmacro*{bytranslator}{%
  \ifnameundef{translator}
    {}
    {\printnames{translator}%
     \setunit{\printdelim{translatortypedelim}}%
     \usebibmacro{translatorstrg}%
     \clearname{translator}}}

\renewbibmacro*{byholder}{%
  \printnames{holder}}

\renewbibmacro*{byeditor+others}{%
  \ifnameundef{editor}
    {}
    {\printnames{editor}%
     \setunit{\printdelim{editortypedelim}}%
     \usebibmacro{editor+othersstrg}%
     \clearname{editor}}%
  \usebibmacro{byeditorx}%
  \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}}

\renewbibmacro*{bytranslator+others}{%
  \ifnameundef{translator}
    {}
    {\printnames{translator}%
     \setunit{\printdelim{translatortypedelim}}%
     \usebibmacro{translator+othersstrg}%
     \clearname{translator}}%
  \usebibmacro{withothers}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{enisskola,
    langid    = {icelandic},
    options   = {useeditor=false},
    year      = {1986},
    title     = {Ensk-íslensk skólaorðabók},
    editor    = {{Jón Skaptason}},
    publisher = {Örn og Örlygur},
    location  = {Reykjavík},
}
@incollection{lucy1997,
    langid    = {british},
    address   = {Cambridge},
    year      = {1997},
    title     = {The linguistics of \lq color\rq},
    booktitle = {Color Categories in Thought and Language},
    author    = {John A. Lucy},
    editor    = {Clyde L. Hardin and Luisa Maffi},
    publisher = {Cambridge University Press},
    location  = {Cambridge},
    pages     = {320--346},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
I cited \autocite{enisskola}
I cited \autocite{lucy1997}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Ensk-íslensk skólaorðabók (1986). Jón Skaptason (ritstj.). Reykjavík: Örn og Örlygur.//Lucy, John A. (1997). „The linguistics of ‘color’“. Í: Color Categories in Thought and Language. Hardin, Clyde L. og Luisa Maffi (ritstj.). Cambridge: Cambridge University Press, bls. 320–346.]